# How to correctly get html file content with laravel storage?

Tags: php, laravel, snappy, laravel-storage

**I'm trying to get the content of an html file** that I've saved before, when I check the html everything is correct, but when I try to access it by doing so :

```
$html = Storage::disk('local')->get(Session('view'));
```

I get a string that contain a part of my html, I don't understand why my html is all destroyed, any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Original file:

```
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/pdfpreview.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <div class="pdfContainer">
        <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/logo.png">
        <div class="soumissionInfoContainer">
            <h2>Soumission</h2>
            <p>Soumission S2-18</p>
            <p>Date: 20-02-2017</p>

        </div>
        <div class="clientInfoContainer">
            <h3>Destinataire</h3>
            <strong>Jean Tremblay</strong>
            <p>1010 St Hubert</p>
            <p>G7H 2B1</p>
            <p>418 555 5555</p>
        </div>
        <table class="previewTable">
            <tbody><tr>
            </tr><tr>
                <th>Quantité</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Prix</th>
            </tr>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </tbody></table>
                    <p class="totalSoumission">TOTAL AVANT
            TAXES: 0$</p>
        <div class="ligne_signature">
            À la signature, ce devis est bon pour travaux et valide 90 jours
        </div>
    </div>
```

The ouput I get from dump `$html`

```
"""
\r\n
    <meta charset="UTF-8">\r\n
    <link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/pdfpreview.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">\r\n
    <div class="pdfContainer">\r\n
        <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/image/logo.png">\r\n
        <div class="soumissionInfoContainer">\r\n
            <h2>Soumission</h2>\r\n
            <p>Soumission S2-18</p>\r\n
            <p>Date: 20-02-2017</p>\r\n
\r\n
        </div>\r\n
        <div class="clientInfoContainer">\r\n
            <h3>Destinataire</h3>\r\n
            <strong>Jean Tremblay</strong>\r\n
            <p>1010 St Hubert</p>\r\n
            <p>G7H 2B1</p>\r\n
            <p>418 555 5555</p>\r\n
        </div>\r\n
        <table class="previewTable">\r\n
            <tbody><tr>\r\n
            </tr><tr>\r\n
                <th>Quantité</th>\r\n
                <th>Description</th>\r\n
                <th>Prix</th>\r\n
            </tr>\r\n
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               </tbody></table>\r\n
```

Comment: Where and how are you dumping the content?

Comment: dump($html), get function return a string which look like my html file

Comment: When I'm using a straight string, it works??? ```Storage::get('1.html')``` but when I set the name in a ```$testValue``` it explode... ex: ~```Storage::get($testValue)```~

Comment: Everything is working when my files are public, I really don't understand, this bug only happen when my files are privates